# SQL Server Management Studio for sql server 2008

Tags: sql

Is there any other version of SQL Server Management Studio except EXPRESS one?
I need one for MS SQL Server 2008 STD version.

I've been trying to search almost everywhere, but it seems there is not.

Can someone agree?

If there is any STANDARD version of this app, i would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Standard shipss with the SSMS as part of the installation package. I think that you cannot find the SSMS, other than Express editions, as a separate download. If you already have SQL Server 2008 Standard, just add the SSMS via the SQL Server 2008 R2 installer